Semaphores for sensor box
I am currently solving the following task for semaphores:

A sensor box consists of 3 different sensors. These sensors collect data which is then written to the local memory by a process. A fourth process then sends the data to a database via a network connection. Due to a shortage of resources, the data must first be sent after it has been collected in order to make room for further data.
To ensure that all sensors have the chance to collect data and that there is no starvation, the sensors should be activated in a strict cyclical sequence (first sensor 1, then sensor 2, then sensor 3 - repeat).
Design a system of semaphores which ensures that the sensors are
activated in the correct order and that data is always transmitted
once between the activation of two sensors.

Primitive Solution
I would have just come up with a primitive solution like the following.
First I initialised the following Semaphores

Semaphore Sensor1Allowed = 1

Semaphore Sensor2Allowed = 0

Semaphore Sensor3Allowed = 0

Semaphore startSendingData = 0
 SendData {
     while(true) {
         startSendingData.wait()
         //sendData
     }
 }

 Sensor1 {
     while(true) {
         Sensor1Allowed.wait()
         //Collect Data
         startSendingData.signal()
         Sensor2Allowed.signal()
     }
 }

 Sensor2 {
     while(true) {
         Sensor2Allowed.wait()
         //Collect Data
         startSendingData.signal()
         Sensor3Allowed.signal()
     }
 }

 Sensor3 {
     while(true) {
         Sensor3Allowed.wait()
         //Collect Data
         startSendingData.signal()
         Sensor1Allowed.signal()
     }
 }



This solution is clearly wrong because the official solution looks like the following:
Official solution

Semaphore Sensor1Allowed = 1

Semaphore Sensor2Allowed = 0

Semaphore Sensor3Allowed = 0

Semaphore startSendingData = 0

Semaphore localStorageEmpty = 1
 Datatransfer {
     while(true):
         sendingData.wait()
         //Send Data
         localStorageEmpty.signal()
}

 Sensor1 {
     while(true):
         Sensor1Allowed.wait()
         localStorageEmpty.wait()
         // Collecting Data 
         sendingData.signal()
         Sensor2Allowed.signal()
 }

 Sensor2 {
     while(true):
         Sensor2Allowed.wait()      
         localStorageEmpty.wait()
         // Collecting Data
         sendingData.signal()
         Sensor3Allowed.signal()
 }

 Sensor3 {
     while(true):
         Sensor3Allowed.wait()      
         localStorageEmpty.wait()
         //Collecting Data
         sendingData.signal()
         Sensor1Allowed.signal()
 }



But why is my primitive solution wrong?
Clearly my primitve solution is wrong. But I don't understand why. I assumed that the local storage is at the beginning empty. So then every process is trying to do something, but everyone except the Sensor1 process has to wait. So Sensor1 starts and collects data. This data is then written into the local storage and then getting send (if in the task they wouldn't have said that this is a fourth process doing I would have just added //sendData instead of solving this with a semaphore). Then after the sending is complete the Sensor2 gets waken up.
The only problem I could see with that is that what happens if we collected data that is too huge to write in the local storage. But I think this problem doesn't get addressed in the official solution as well.
In my opinion even the official solution looks kinda weird. Because I understand the task like the following: if a sensor starts it collects a certain amount of data(less then the local storage place). Then if this is complete a process starts which is trying to write the data in the local storage (which is at the beginning empty). After that a process starts which sends the content of the local storage to the database. With that I really don't see the purpose of the Semaphore localStorageEmpty.
My question now is if you could explain the official solution to me in more detail and also explain why my primitive solution fails. If you come up with a different solution then the official solution I also would be happy to see that.
